# Juniper Networks Docker container complains about Free Hugepages not being available

Tags: docker, juniper

In my CentOS 7.2, I run openjnpr-container-vmx, but get error:

```
[root@centos ~]# docker run  juniper/openjnpr-container-vmx
Juniper Networks vMX Docker Light Container
 
Linux b32d308d36eb 4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 8 10:59:10 UTC 2020 x86_64
 
CPU Model ................................ Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 v5 @ 3.40GHz
CPU affinity of this container ........... 0-7
KVM hardware virtualization extension .... yes
Total System Memory ...................... 15 GB
Free Hugepages ........................... none! Please provision at least 1G (512x2MB or 1x1GB) hugepage
Check for container privileged mode ...... yes
Check for sudo/root privileges ........... yes
Loop mount filesystem capability ......... no
docker access ............................ no (optional)

lcpu affinity ............................  0-7

NUMA node(s):        1
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7

1 optional features missing. Ignored
2 failed system dependencies. Terminating
```

===

my dedicated server hardware information:

```
[root@centos ~]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.4Gi       395Mi       832Mi        13Gi        13Gi
Swap:         7.8Gi       2.0Mi       7.8Gi
```

CPU model:
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 v5 @ 3.40GHz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the OpenJNPR-Container-vMX [Enable Hugepages](https://github.com/Juniper/OpenJNPR-Container-vMX#enable-hugepages) section:

> #### Enable hugepages
>
> Define at least 1024 x 2MB hugepages or 2 x 1GB hugepages via kernel options by adding
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=2"
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="hugepages=1024"
> ```
>
> to the file /etc/default/grub, followed by running update-grub and reboot:
>
> ```
> $ sudo update-grub
> $ reboot
> ```
>
> Once the system is back, check the availability of hugepages (the example shown has 16x1GB pages reserved):
>
> ```
> $ cat /proc/meminfo |grep Huge
> AnonHugePages:         0 kB
> ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
> HugePages_Total:      16
> HugePages_Free:       16
> HugePages_Rsvd:        0
> HugePages_Surp:        0
> Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB
> ```